# Memory-swap limits

Tags: docker

According to [the docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/#--memory-swap-details) if `--memory-swap` is unset, and `--memory` is set, the container can use twice as much `swap` as the `--memory` setting, if the host container has swap memory configured.

So the two following commands are equivalent :

```
 docker run --rm -it -m 128m progrium/stress --vm 1 --vm-bytes 300M --vm-hang 0

 docker run --rm -it -m 128m --memory-swap 384m progrium/stress --vm 1 --vm-bytes 300M --vm-hang 0
```

Unfortunately, it does not give the same result.

```
docker run --rm -it -m 128m progrium/stress --vm 1 --vm-bytes 300M --vm-hang 0
stress: info: [1] dispatching hogs: 0 cpu, 0 io, 1 vm, 0 hdd
stress: dbug: [1] using backoff sleep of 3000us
stress: dbug: [1] --> hogvm worker 1 [5] forked
stress: dbug: [5] allocating 314572800 bytes ...
stress: dbug: [5] touching bytes in strides of 4096 bytes ...
stress: FAIL: [1] (416) <-- worker 5 got signal 9
stress: WARN: [1] (418) now reaping child worker processes
stress: FAIL: [1] (422) kill error: No such process
stress: FAIL: [1] (452) failed run completed in 4s

# docker run --rm -it -m 128m --memory-swap 384m progrium/stress --vm 1 --vm-bytes 300M --vm-hang 0
stress: info: [1] dispatching hogs: 0 cpu, 0 io, 1 vm, 0 hdd
stress: dbug: [1] using backoff sleep of 3000us
stress: dbug: [1] --> hogvm worker 1 [5] forked
stress: dbug: [5] allocating 314572800 bytes ...
stress: dbug: [5] touching bytes in strides of 4096 bytes ...
stress: dbug: [5] sleeping forever with allocated memory
```

It seems to me that there is an error in the documentation. In fact, if `--memory-swap` is unset, and `--memory` is set, the value of `--memory-swap` is set to twice as much as the `--memory` parameter. I searched in [docker's code](https://github.com/opencontainers/runc/blob/master/libcontainer/cgroups/fs/memory.go) but I didn't find anything that confirms or denies what I just explained.

Could anyone explain this incoherence.

Comment: Hey, did you ever figure this out? I'm now seeing something equally bizarre: if I do set `--memory-swap` to the same number as `--memory`, but then look into `docker inspect` output, the `MemorySwap` show as `-1`, which means "unlimited".

Answer (score 0):

[Docker Documentation on Resources](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/#--memory-swap-details) now explains this use case

> If --memory-swap is unset, and --memory is set, the container can use as much swap as the --memory setting, if the host container has swap memory configured. For instance, if --memory="300m" and --memory-swap is not set, the container can use 600m in total of memory and swap.

I believe that the confusion could be related to a 'poor' selection of words. The parameter seems to refer to Swap only memory, when in reality, it's referencing RAM + Swap. Calling it `--total-memory` could make it clearer.

> --memory-swap represents the total amount of memory and swap that can be used, and --memory controls the amount used by non-swap memory. So if --memory="300m" and --memory-swap="1g", the container can use 300m of memory and 700m (1g - 300m) swap.